# Hidden cordova inAppBrowser has no event for shown status

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

The cordova inAppBrowser has the next option on opening (as mentioned in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/):

> **hidden**: set to yes to create the browser and load the page, but not show it. The loadstop event fires when loading is complete. Omit
>   or set to no (default) to have the browser open and load normally.

The problem is that **I want to detect and execute code when the browser is completely rendered on the screen of the device**. The api provides "loadstop" event, but it's executed before the device's screen is showing the web page.

Is there any way to detect this moment?

**EDITED:**

This is what I'm trying (not exactly but similar):

```
inappService.runScript( 
    function (params) { 
        function handleVisibilityChange() {
            if (!document.hidden) {
                $('input#otp')[0].focus(); 
            }
        }
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false); 
);
```

But "visibilitychange" occurs when the page is preloaded hidden. Any idea of how I could detect it with javascript on the web page? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `inAppBrowser` has no event for when the it completely renders the page. However, you can try using its `executeScript()` method which allows to inject your own JavaScript. That allows you to use whatever technique you like for detecting the complete rendering of the page.

Comment: Hi Racil, That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Something like this (look at it as pseudo-code): 

`inappService.runScript(
function (params) {
function handleVisibilityChange() {
if (!document.hidden) {
$('input#otp')[0].focus();
}
}
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);
);`

But "visibilitychange" occurs when the page is preloaded hidden. Any idea of how I could detect it with javascript on the web page?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Posting code in comment is not a good idea and it is hard to read. You can edit your question and add information there.